# Storing raster data in a Data Lake

Tags: databricks, gis, geospatial, raster, delta-lake

In our organisation much of our data is stored in Delta Lake tables in the Azure infrastructure, with Databricks integrated. I want to be able to work with raster data (for example satellite images) in a cloud computing, distributed environment. What strategies and processes do you use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It's really a broad question - work can mean multiple things

1. Data ingestion from source formats
2. Data transformation into forms suitable for analysis
3. Doing analysis on the GIS data, including visualizing the data.

On Databricks, there are multiple options:

- You can ingest data either as binary into Delta Lake tables or convert them from the source formats (for example, Databricks Labs project called [Mosaic](https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/) allows you to ingest WKT, WKB, GeoJSON).
- [Mosaic](https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/) also allows to index geo data & perform many different operations on them, including visualizations.
- Databricks Runtime also includes a [number of geospatial functions](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-h3-geospatial-functions.html), and almost each new version adds more functionality.